# thread starvation with boost::lock_guard

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

i am trying to learn the boost library and was going through examples of boost::thread.

The example below illustrates the usage of the **boost::lock_guard** for thread synchronization, ensuring that the access to **std::cout** is not concurrent:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void wait(const int secs) {
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(secs));
}

boost::mutex mutex;

void thread1() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        wait(1); // <-- all works fine if wait is placed here
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mutex);
        std::cout << boost::format("thread A here %d\n") % i ;
    }
}

void thread2() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        wait(1); //  <-- all works fine if wait is placed here
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mutex);
        std::cout << boost::format("thread B here %d\n") % i;
    }

}

int main() {
    boost::thread t1(thread1);
    boost::thread t2(thread2);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

The results where pretty much what one would expect, i.e. alternating messages by the two threads printed:

```
thread A here 0
thread B here 0
thread A here 1
thread B here 1
thread A here 2
thread B here 2
thread A here 3
thread B here 3
thread A here 4
thread B here 4
...
```

However, a small modification -- moving the wait call *inside* the scope of the lock guard -- led to a surprise:

```
void thread1() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mutex);
        wait(1); // <== !
        std::cout << boost::format("thread A here %d\n") % i ;
    }
}

void thread2() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mutex);
        wait(1);  // <== !
        std::cout << boost::format("thread B here %d\n") % i;
    }
```

Now either thead1 or thread2 wins the initial "race" for the mutex and then wins again and again on each loop iteration, thereby starving the other thread!

Example output:

```
thread B here 0
thread B here 1
thread B here 2
thread B here 3
thread B here 4
thread B here 5
thread B here 6
thread B here 7
thread B here 8
thread B here 9
thread A here 0
thread A here 1
thread A here 2
thread A here 3
thread A here 4
thread A here 5
thread A here 6
thread A here 7
thread A here 8
thread A here 9
```

Can anybody please explain why this is the case?

Comment: This is normal.  There's no guarantee of fitness, especially visible when you have a thread *not* own a lock for less than a nanosecond.  There's just no chance for the other thread to acquire the lock.  Your first result is a random outcome as well.

Comment: The typical mutex implementations do not guarantee against starvation, so your results are as valid as anything. In your first code, you have a very high probability of running the threads in a lockstep fashion, in your latter approach the thread will try to re-aquire the mutex immediately after it unlocks it.

Comment: @nos: I couldn't imagine how to prevent threads from running lockstep given this example. Your wording "_typical_ implementations do not guard against" suggests that this is actually possible. Do you have a paper (or even an implementation) at hand?

Comment: @Daemon Which of the two approaches are you referring to ? in the first piece of code there's really not any contention at all, the wait call makes the threads alternate. In the 2. example the threads would alternate too if the mutex implementation uses a fifo queue for the tasks blocked on the mutex, which they are not on the platform of the OP (which is quite typical on unix implementations)

Comment: @nos: I am referring to the second snippet. I could hardly imagine how one could have a "non-typical" mutex that avoids threads running lockstep, since it's being held while threads go to sleep. It would have to be something like how Windows completion ports work, which wake another blocked thread if one of the active ones blocks on I/O. But this kind of thing wouldn't be valid behavior for a mutex. Even when a thread is not executing, it is still inside the "mutually exclusive" program section while holding the mutex. Otherwise, being re-scheduled would also mean releasing a mutex.

Comment: @damon It's quite simple, the mutex does not use a fifo queue on the blocked tasks. e.g. say thread1 grabs the mutex, thread2 blocks. Then thread 1 sleeps, and unlock the mutex. The OS starts scheduling thread2 that was blocked on the mutex. But by the time the scheduler has awoken thread2, thread1 managed to grab the mutex once more - thread1 was already running, and thread2 arrives just a bit late to the party, and gets blocked again.

Comment: @nos: But even if the queue of blocked tasks is not FIFO, an already blocked task that is being scheduled will surely always acquire the mutex faster than a task that has just released it, then performs some register cleanup, performs a jump (to a likely no longer instruction-cached location, after sleeping for one second), and does the syscall setup and syscall again. If thread2 is scheduled at all _and_ already in the queue, but thread1 first has to do its dance worth a thousand clock cycles, I don't see how this could ever happen (not practically and not in theory).

Comment: Well maybe with a spinlock using atomic ops, but even then it's rather unlikely. Possible, though.

Comment: @Damon The thread that unlocks it may just do a simple syscall to notify the scheduler to make anyone that is locked on the mutex runnable, and then return to the task that unlocked the mutex, which will grab it again in this case (there's no guarantee that unlocking a mutex preempt the task that unlocks it). Or imagine it was an SMP system, thread2 might be unblocked and the kernel runs thread 2 on CPU2, thread1 was running on CPU1 and returns to running on CPU1, and it'd grab the mutex again (it wouldn't make sense for thread1 to wait for thread2 actually being run on entierly different CPU)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because after the lock is acquired the wait call causes the second thread to begin executing. Since the second thread cannot acquire the lock it goes into a wait-state until the lock is available. In your case the lock does not become available until the first thread completes it's loop.